# Python writing to file works fine when done manually, but cron fails

Tags: python, cron

I wrote a python script which writes to a text file, with the code that looks like this:

```
playercountlog = open("PMCcount.txt", "a")

playercountlog.write(time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"));
playercountlog.write(" ");
playercountlog.write(time.strftime("%I:%M:%S"));
playercountlog.write(" ");
playercountlog.write(count);
playercountlog.write("\n")
playercountlog.close()
```

This script works fine when executed as root (python program.py), but when added to cron like so:

```
* * * * * /user/bin/python /home/labtec901/program.py
```

nothing gets written to the file.

I've chmodded both the program and the txt file to 777 just to be sure, but no difference.  What gives?

Answer (score 8):

Your line in `crontab` should probably be something along the lines of:

```
* * * * * cd /home/labtec901 && /usr/bin/python /home/labtec901/program.py
```

This fixes two issues: Your program is now running in `labtec901`'s home directory (instead of `root`'s directory, if that's whose crontab it is), and the path to Python has been corrected - from `/user/bin/python` to `/usr/bin/python`.

Alternatively, if you don't want the `cd` command in the crontab, just put is as the first lines of the python program:

```
import os
os.chdir('/home/labtec901')
```

**OR**, you can specify the absolute path of the file to open:

```
playercountlog = open("/home/labtec901/PMCcount.txt", "a")
```

Answer (score 4):

The cron job has a different working directory. So, either it wrote somewhere else or failed because you didn't have rights there. Use an absolute file name instead.

Comment: Specifically, cron typically runs jobs in the home directory of the user whose crontab it is.

Comment: @JohnZwinck - hmmm, I hadn't thought about that. I typically schedule outside of my own account and use absolute paths.

Answer (score 0):

### `--user` is the answer (for me)

I just found this post as I encountered the exact same issue (years later).

I tried a lot, e.g. the proposed `os.chdir('...')` which did not work.

Eventually I execute the file as:
`0 * * * * python3 /home/me/folder/script.py --user` and --user did the trick for me.

Note, if no `cd /home/me/folder/ && python3 /home/me/folder/script.py --user` is used before executing the script, the output is written directly to the home directory `me`.

**As a side note:** This happens even if the python script says `with open('right_here.txt', 'a+') as file: [..]`, so indicating that the file is in the same folder. CRON sees that differently.